# why opcode a5a5a5a5 is shown when the program gets stuck in ARMv7?

Tags: debugging, arm

My code for ARMv7 stopped running at this instruction STRGE r10,[r5,#0x5a5].Its opcode is a5a5a5a5.I have googled and found that this sequence is some thing special and many people observe this while the system crashes. I would like to know what is special about this sequence and what can I infer when this occurs.

Comment: Your 'PC' is pointing to some physical address that has no device.  Ie, you have 128MB or RAM but have tried to look at 258MB of RAM and there is nothing there (as an example of what is wrong and not your particular case).  Usually you will get a fault if this happens with an MMU enabled and tables are correct.  The `STRGE r10,[r5,#0x5a5]` is not special.  The address (PC) you are looking at that matters and the instruction looks like 'a5' or alternating 1/0 that a hardware person will pull bits when you look at a non existent device.

Comment: I think this might be a mechanism for the debugger to react to being unable to read memory, rather than the actual value of any instruction read from the hardware. That would make it a kind of magic number.